# How to support OpenGL versions < 3.3 in GLSL with layout specifiers?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have this OpenGL program that uses layout specifiers in its shaders. I would like it to be able to support OpenGL versions under 3.3 (when layout specifiers were introduced).

Is there any way to replace layout specifiers to support earlier OpenGL versions?

Comment: Just let the GLSL linker decide on the location(s) and query them using [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml)?

Comment: @G.M.: Or set them before linking via `glBindAttribLocation()`?

Comment: "*I would like it to be able to support OpenGL versions under 3.3*" Um, why? Most implementations below 3.3 are abandoned and thus are likely riddled with bugs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so the way to do this is to not use `layout`s, and instead use `in`. For example, if this is one vertex on your vbo:

```
//  | Coordinates |     Colors    | Tex Coord |
    {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.5f,  1.f, 0.f}
```

Then this would be the vertex shader:

```c
in vec3 coordinates;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texCoord;
```

Notice how the number in the `vec` declaration matches the number of values in the vbo.

Comment: "*Ok, so the way to do this is to not use layouts, and instead use in.*" That's not an "instead"; `in` has to be there *regardless* of version. `layout(location` is a *modifier* for an `in` declaration, not a replacement.